# Contour Lines Extraction Based on Heat Map

Tags: gis, qgis, mapbox

I've been playing with Mapbox's blog post about [converting heat maps to contour lines](http://mapbox.com/blog/contour-lines-density-mapping/), and I'm stuck at the extraction part of this process.

I used the CSV plugin to create a vector layer of points, then a heat map raster layer based on that, but I can't seem to be able to see the contour lines based on that raster layer after that. When I looked at the properties and selected categorized, it didn't seem to have any symbols listed.

I'm guessing this is probably some kind of type error since I had to create the raster layer based off of map units and not meters, but I don't know how to correct it. What am I missing?

Comment: also asked at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41389/contour-lines-raster-extraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey dokey. After the holiday weekend I figured it out.

It was basically a type error with the CRS. Although it's not explicitly stated, I got in touch with MapBox and found out they were working in Google Mercator. It's also a perfectly acceptable CRS to use when you eventually have to import the .shp file into MapBox/Tile Mill.